# How to make async request in cycle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, cycle

```
var userName = 'realgrumpycat';
var moreAvailable = true;
var lastId = '';

while (moreAvailable)
{
    getPhotosDataFromRequest(userName, lastId).then(function (data)
    {
        moreAvailable = data.more_available;
        lastId = data[data.length - 1].id;
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

**getPhotosDataFromRequest()** returns new Promise() and JSON with data. I'd like to execute this method several times at **cyscle**. But as I see at debugger, while loop executes so fast, that doesn't step into **promise then block**

Comment: It will step into `then block` after promise resolve

Comment: @rakaz No it won't. It will loop forever and the anonymous function passed into `then` will never be entered regardless of the promise resolving, because of the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try using function recursion:

```
var userName = 'realgrumpycat';
var lastId = '';

var getPhotos = function()
{
    getPhotosDataFromRequest(userName, lastId).then(function (data)
    {
        lastId = data[data.length - 1].id;
        console.log(data);

        if (data.more_available) 
        {
            getPhotos();
        }
    });
};

getPhotos();
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that recursive asynchronous control flows with `Promise`s can block, because instead of `setTimeout` they use micro-task scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

just as iterative alternative (as concept), but **not really a solution** in real life, because of performance and limits:

```
//i try to use here es5 only
var userName = 'realgrumpycat';
var moreAvailable = true;//<-- can be removed
var lastId = ''; //<-- can be removed
var maxRequests = 1000; //e.g. max 1000 requests

//create empty promise to resolve later
var resolveStart = null;
var request = new Promise(function(resolve){
  resolveStart = resolve;
});

//append 1000 potential requests
for(var i = 0; i < maxRequests; i++) {
  request = request.then(createRequestPromise);
}

//here you probably should differ the "done" rejection and other errors
request.catch(function(){});

//now resolve the first promise, with empty string, to start the request chain
resolveStart('');

function createRequestPromise(lastId) {
    return getPhotosDataFromRequest(userName, lastId).then(function (data)
    {
        lastId = data[data.length - 1].id;
        console.log(data);
        //stop the chain by rejection
        if (!data.more_available) return Promise.reject('done');

        return lastId;
    });
}
```